# What determines whether liquid droplets will combine or push into each other?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

In trying to understand some fluid-dynamic principles, I am trying to discern between a couple water droplet interactions. [This droplet video](https://youtu.be/K8Wx2PHIYGI) demonstrates the scenarios properly, but unfortunately doesn’t afford a ton of explanation related to the supporting math.

**Combining Droplets**
Somewhere around 00:15 two droplets combine in the bottom corner of the screen.

[image: two droplets combining]

**Cohabiting Droplets**
Whereas the video seems a bit more interested in droplets chasing each other.

[image: a droplet chasing another]

Forces related to surface tension are definitely at play - and perhaps density as well. But I'm trying to understand what exactly would determine whether two droplets combine or maintain some level of independence. For ex, if we were to track two colliding droplets that were to combine, what threshold in the formula would need to be crossed to convert from colliding to unionized droplets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind soul on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/cem8vz/what_determines_whether_two_liquid_droplets_will/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) found the [study](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01338286/file/Article2.pdf) from the video in question. From what I understand, droplets in contact with each other will eventually combine, but that process is slowed depending on the concentration of each liquid. In the source video, those concentrations refer to varying mixtures of propylene glycol and water. Two droplets of differing concentrations will take longer to coalesce, which creates an extended 'chase sequence.' Here's the related quote from the study:

> Droplets of sufficiently different concentrations can undergo a
>   prolonged ‘chasing phase’26 as explained by Riegler and Lazar30 (Fig.
>   1b). Fluid is directly exchanged between the droplets, as visualized
>   by a fluorescent dye (Supplementary Video 7). This exchange of fluid
>   leads to a surface tension gradient across both  the  droplets,  where
>   the  droplet  of  lower  surface  tension  ‘chases’  the  droplet  of 
>   higher  surface tension, which in turn ‘flees’ away30. Additional
>   subtleties of short-range interactions can be  obtained  by  adjusting
>   concentrations  and  volumes  (Supplementary  Information,  Extended 
>   Data Fig. 7).

And one of the provided figures:

[image: supplemental figure from study]